# Grunt is not correctly building locally - missing files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-requirejs

Grunt has suddenly stopped building correctly locally. It's not building assets that are served by Angular, and the console is giving the following message:

`Uncaught Error: inc/../../../common/js/sv-common missing inc/../../../common/js/./lib/ngui-sortable`

EDIT: more detail

```
Uncaught Error: ../../common/js/sv-common missing ../../common/js/./lib/ngui-sortable
> main @ www-app.js:296call
> Dep @ www-app.js:166
> main @ www-app.js:291call
> Dep @ www-app.js:166main @ www-app.js:291
> req @ www-app.js:359
> (anonymous function) @ www-app.js:3737
> (anonymous function) @ www-app.js:3738
```

I've done a fresh checkout of the repo, and no one else on my team is having the same issue. The missing file is absolutely in my local repo, and it's also in the tmp/ directory of it. I honestly have no idea how to debug this.

```
$ grunt --stack -d
Running "jshint:local" (jshint) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/tasks/jshint.js
>> 0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.

Running "clean:local" (clean) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/tasks/clean.js
Cleaning tmp/...OK
Cleaning /opt/survata/deploy...OK

Running "less:local" (less) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/tasks/less.js
File tmp/htdocs/assets/20150929_165903/www/survata-www.css created.
File tmp/htdocs/assets/20150929_165903/www/dashboard.css created.
File tmp/htdocs/assets/20150929_165903/surveys/surveys-app.css created.
File tmp/htdocs/assets/20150929_165903/take/surveys-app.css created.
File tmp/htdocs/assets/20150929_165903/surveywall/survey-wall.css created.
File tmp/htdocs/surveywall/style/build/survey-wall.css created.
File subdomains/surveywall/style/build/survey-wall.css created.

Running "copy:assets" (copy) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/tasks/copy.js
Created 50 directories, copied 428 files

Running "shell:requirejs" (shell) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-shell/tasks/shell.js

Running "copy:common_deploy" (copy) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/tasks/copy.js
Created 10 directories, copied 10 files

Running "shell:pygreen" (shell) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-shell/tasks/shell.js

Running "shell:replace_subdomain" (shell) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-shell/tasks/shell.js

Running "replace:local" (replace) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-text-replace/tasks/text-replace.js

Running "copy:deploy_local" (copy) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/tasks/copy.js
Created 388 directories, copied 2148 files

Running "shell:deploy_local" (shell) task
[D] Task source: /workspace/survata-com/node_modules/grunt-shell/tasks/shell.js

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? Is there any more to the stack trace? Can you trying running `grunt` with `grunt --stack` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the stacktrace hasn't been very helpful so far. The error only shows up when going to the local URL and opening the dev tools. I'll update with the output of grunt --stack -d just in case though.

Comment: Ah. I understand now, so you're saying this a runtime error in the browser? Can you show the stack trace from the browser?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? I pasted the actual error in the console, not sure where to get anything more detailed than that